# Term for the Non-uniformity of Some Human Responses

Tags: statistics

I'd read some years ago about a phenomenon whereby, when asked, humans will tend to give some particular response more than others when asked for a 'random' value.  The very well-known one is the tendency to respond with 37 as a 'number between one and 100, and there may be a tendency to favor one of a set of four quadrants of a square, etc.

My recollection is that there is a formal term for these non-uniform human responses like, "[something] variables."

Can anyone post the correct term for these variables?

Thank you.

Comment: *Bias*? ${}{}{}$

Comment: I think bias a correct term, but the specific term I am looking for is "_______ variables," and I think the blank was the last name of the statistician who did some amount of research on these kinds of occurrences. Thank you, nonetheless.

Comment: Google finally coughed forth something - the "Blue-seven Phenomenon."  It's still not the term that I think I am looking for, but I believe it describes what I am after.